# Image texture partially rendering but shown completely in render preview?

Tags: rendering, uv

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening! Here's my [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCVet_J6a1MqioNJpLR8Itp-8F16Pyrb/view?usp=sharing) for anyone who wants to take a look.

Here's what I see in Blender: [image]

And here's what the render looks like:[image]

And help, ideas, or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You have some objects than are hidden in viewport render preview but not in final render, so make sure that they are also hidden in final render if you don't want to see them:

[image]